# How can I get my menu bar to be center and stretch all the way across?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I've tried a lot of different things here but I just can't seem to get my menu bar to stretch all the way across the page. There's a small gap on the left side. Am I just missing something here?

Also so far this is the only way I've been able to get my footer somewhat centered at the bottom of the page. Every time I set the left and right margins to auto it puts the footer in line with the menu bar. Is there a better way to do this as well?

Thank You.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Connor Lepert: Homepage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
    charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="logo.png">
        <style>
            @font-face {
              font-family: Vanadine; 
              src: url(vanadine.ttf);
            }

            body {
              background-image: url(bckgrnd.jpg); 
              background-size: 100%; 
              background-repeat: no-repeat; 
              font-family: sans-serif; 
              color: white;
            }

            a {
              color: white; 
              font-family: Vanadine; 
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:hover {
              color: yellow;
            }

            p {
              color: white; 
              font-family: Vanadine;
            }

            footer {
              position: fixed; 
              display: block; 
              margin-left: 45%; 
              margin-right: 45%; 
              text-align: center; 
              margin-top: 320px;
            }

            #siteid {
              margin-left: auto; 
              margin-top: auto
            }

            #menubar {
              background-color: #ABADB0; 
              width: 100%; 
              height: 20px; 
              display: block; 
              margin-left: auto; 
              margin-right: auto; 
              margin-top: auto; 
              text-align: center; 
              word-spacing: 20px; 
              position: fixed; 
            }

            #header {
              display: block; 
              margin-left:auto; 
              margin-right: auto; 
              text-align: center; 
              margin-top: 330px;
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="siteid"><img src="logowhite.png" width="50px" alt="Personal logo"/></div>
        <div id="header"><img src="header.png" width="400" alt="Lepert"/></div>
        <div id="menubar">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About</a>
            <a href=mailto:clepert13@gmail.com>Contact</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="scrapyard.html">ScrapYard</a>
        </div>

    <footer>©<a href=> 2015 by Connor Lepert </a> <br> <p></p> </footer>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must just add a margin:0 to your body

Answer (score 0):

I create a wrapper class and wrap the code that needs to be centered within it. Here's an example:

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
}

<html>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div><!--wrapper-->
    </div><!--navbar-->
</html>
```

You just need to make sure that you place the wrapper class before the content, but after the background that needs to repeat. That is shown in my example. Otherwise, you'll have everything centered like it needs to be, but your background will cut off because it's being contained in a 960px area.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Artefact](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835691/artefact) already said, adding `margin:0` to your `body` will remove the gap beneath your menubar.

**Just a little explaining:**
This gap is caused by your browser, in fact every browser has some presets for some elements (i.e. the size of a `h1` and how links are displayed) and those presets differ from browser to browser.
For this reason most people will use css resets to have a clean starting point for their own css.

There are several resources for resets out there like the one from [meyerweb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) that you can use or you can simply write your own.